# Accessing details of ajax response JSON

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

I have a really stupid beginner jquery question, even if I saw a lot of similar question here:

From PHP with ajax I send this:

```
public function to_json() {
    return json_encode(array( 'test_id' => 'test_value' ));
}
```

In the jquery file's success part I put:

```
function(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

And it shows this in the alert window:

```
{"test_id":"test_value"}
```

Which is fine, I guess, but if I change the function to this:

```
function(data) {
    alert(data.test_id);
}
```

I got:

```
undefined
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I missing?

To set the `Content-Type` HTTP response header to `application/json` in your PHP script:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Or to set the `dataType` parameter to `json` on the client:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/foo.php',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
       alert(data.test_id);
   }
});
```

The first is preferred because this way your server side script properly indicates to the client the content type it is using. And jQuery is intelligent enough to use this reponse header and automatically parse the response from the server before feeding it to the `success` callback.

Comment: Thank you very much, the second solution worked, somehow, the first one didn't. Should I put the header info into a special place? I put it into the very beginning of the function of the PHP file, the ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to use the function parseJSON

reference:http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

That function converts the json string into a javascript object

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse it like this:

```
function(data) {
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
    alert(obj.test_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers posted so far worked for me.

This is what I had to do to get it working:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/foo.php',
   success: function(data) {
       var json = data.responseJSON;
       alert(json.test_id);
   }
});
```